# How to convert list containing string of elemet to list in python

Tags: python, list

input

```
res=['QA9.1', 'QA4,QA12,QA15,QA16', 'QA9.1']
```

output

```
res1=['QA9.1', 'QA4','QA12','QA15','QA16', 'QA9.1']
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey LeoE, Thank you for your input very new to the python. will try from next time

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a list comprehension:

```
res=['QA9.1', 'QA4,QA12,QA15,QA16', 'QA9.1']
res1 = [x for a in res for x in a.split(',')]
print(res1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
res=['QA9.1', 'QA4,QA12,QA15,QA16', 'QA9.1']
res1 = []
for x in res:
    y = x.split(",")
    for z in y:
        res1.append(z)
print(res1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = ['QA9.1', 'QA4,QA12,QA15,QA16', 'QA9.1']
res1 = list()
for item in res:
    res1.extend(item.split(','))
print(res1)
```